# What's the runtime of Python's strip()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

What's the runtime of Python's strip()?

Since remove is O(n) for a single char, is strip O(n^2) for a string?

Comment: There is no `str.delete` on a `str`, they are immutable. Do you mean `str.remove` which creates new string?

Comment: What do you mean by `str.remove`? it does not exist…

Comment: ^oops sorry, yes I meant the remove() operation. updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is also O(N) only. Quoting the code corresponding to the plain `strip` which strips the spaces, [from the version 2.7.9](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Objects/stringobject.c#l1855)

```
Py_LOCAL_INLINE(PyObject *)
do_strip(PyStringObject *self, int striptype)
{
    char *s = PyString_AS_STRING(self);
    Py_ssize_t len = PyString_GET_SIZE(self), i, j;

    i = 0;
    if (striptype != RIGHTSTRIP) {
        while (i < len && isspace(Py_CHARMASK(s[i]))) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    j = len;
    if (striptype != LEFTSTRIP) {
        do {
            j--;
        } while (j >= i && isspace(Py_CHARMASK(s[j])));
        j++;
    }

    if (i == 0 && j == len && PyString_CheckExact(self)) {
        Py_INCREF(self);
        return (PyObject*)self;
    }
    else
        return PyString_FromStringAndSize(s+i, j-i);
}
```

It first starts from the left and increments the variable `i`, till it finds a non-space character and then it starts from the right and decrements `j` till it finds a non-space character. And finally the string between `i` and `j` is returned with this

```
PyString_FromStringAndSize(s+i, j-i)
```

But on the other hand, [the `strip` which removes the set of characters](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Objects/stringobject.c#l1821), is slightly complicated but fairly similar.

```
Py_LOCAL_INLINE(PyObject *)
do_xstrip(PyStringObject *self, int striptype, PyObject *sepobj)
{
    char *s = PyString_AS_STRING(self);
    Py_ssize_t len = PyString_GET_SIZE(self);
    char *sep = PyString_AS_STRING(sepobj);
    Py_ssize_t seplen = PyString_GET_SIZE(sepobj);
    Py_ssize_t i, j;

    i = 0;
    if (striptype != RIGHTSTRIP) {
        while (i < len && memchr(sep, Py_CHARMASK(s[i]), seplen)) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    j = len;
    if (striptype != LEFTSTRIP) {
        do {
            j--;
        } while (j >= i && memchr(sep, Py_CHARMASK(s[j]), seplen));
        j++;
    }

    if (i == 0 && j == len && PyString_CheckExact(self)) {
        Py_INCREF(self);
        return (PyObject*)self;
    }
    else
        return PyString_FromStringAndSize(s+i, j-i);
}
```

It is the same as the previous one, but it has the extra `memchr(sep, Py_CHARMASK(s[j]), seplen)` check every time. So, the time complexity of this becomes O(N * M), where `M` is the length of the actual string of characters to be stripped.

Comment: @jamylak that's cool. string slicing could be O(1) in cases with a step of 1 as well then, yeah?

Comment: @Ryan True it just increments reference and returns the exact same string https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Objects/stringobject.c#l1322

Comment: @jamylak: `PyString_FromStringAndSize()` returns a *copy*. Otherwise the question who owns what parts might complicate garbage collection. It returns the same string only for `s[0:len(s):1]` case.

Comment: `s.strip(sep)` is `O(len(s) * len(sep))` i.e., `O(n*m)`, not `O(n*n)` where `m` (in practice) is bounded by alphabet size (`256` in this case).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are right :-) Updated my answer.